# How can I determine if user's input is empty?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, javacc

I am writing code to generate a JavaCC parser, which will read a user's input and check if it is in any one of a set of languages defined in my code.

One condition on allowable input is that it must not be empty - i.e., the user must enter some block of characters (with length greater than or equal to 1) other than white space `" "`.

I would like to be able to determine if the user's input is empty, so that an error message can be printed out on the screen in that case.

I have written a production (a.k.a rule) that gets the user's input; it's called `Input()` and is declared to be void.
In the main method, I have tried to write code which determines if the user's input is empty, by writing:

```
if parser.Input() == null {
  // print error message onto the screen
}
```

However, I get an error message on the terminal when I try to compile, stating that a 'void' type is not allowed here (I am sure this is referring to Input).

Could I please have a hint/hints for getting around this issue?

Comment: A void method returns no value.  So comparing the value returned from a void function to null (or anything else) makes no sense.  This is why the compiler is reporting an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the Input production like this

```
boolean Input() : {
} {
    <EOF>
    {return true;}
|
   ... // other possibilities here
   {return false;}
}
```

Then, in the main method, you can write

```
if( parser.Input() ) {
    ... // report error
}
```

This solves the problem of reporting the error.

However you may also want to report the language found.  For that you could make an enumeration type and have `Input` return a member of the enumeration.  `EMPTY` could be one of the possibilities.

```
Language lang = parser.Input() ;
switch( lang ) {
    case EMPTY:
        ... // report error
    break ;
    case LANGA:
        ...
    break ; 
    ... // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your type method so this can return a value and you can validate the result, when you do this but change the comparison like this:

`if null==parser.Input(){
//print error message on screen
}`

Another option is to validate data inside your Input method so you keep it like void.